# SQLite calculate DOB given age

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I am learning more about SQL and working with dates. I'm using the titanic dataset which does not natively have dates, but I thought I could derive some dates to start playing with using date of titanic sinking ("1912-04-15") and age column. I've been googling and past hour and unable to make progress, hoping to get some help here! Seems to be plenty of info on how to do the opposite of this example (derive age from DOB).

I'm using SQLite and looking for something like the following.

```
SELECT 
    date("1912-04-15", "- " || CAST(age*365 AS INT) || " days") AS dob
FROM titanic
```

In short, how do you take a static date and add a dynamic number of days given another data column?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes turns out i was VERY close! removing the space did the trick!

```
SELECT 
    date("1912-04-15", "-" || CAST(age*365 AS INT) || " days") AS dob
FROM titanic
```